# Django Mezzanine tagging for user accounts

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

Can anyone provide an example of a exposing "add tag" functionality to a public user.  I am not clear how to and where to save tags submitted from a public facing form. And how to make them function on a that form they way function in a blogpost page in the admin.

In this case I have QuestionModel - a model that stores user submitted questions - extending mezzanine's abstract "Displayable" model directly.  A user can submit a question with tags through a standard django form. On my public facing form I have an input field for comma separated tags.  In the view I am not able to save the cleaned form data to 'keywords', which appears to be an attribute belonging to another class that is extended by Displayable.

Thanks,
Matt